# No he logrado que al escribir dentro de un input un numero luego este pase a un select y se reste -1 y luego se multiplique - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

buen dia necesito que al escribir dentro de un input un numero este aparezca dentro de un select restándose uno y que se multiplique dos veces por dos en select, ejemplo dentro del input agrego un 10 entonces en select debe aparecerme 9 , 18 , 32 .

```js
function pruebas() {
    return (
        <div>

  <input type="number" placeholder="ingrese un numero" />
   <br/>          

<select name="tipo_cancha" class="form-control" >
<option value='no' selected>seleccionar</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  
  
</select> 
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default pruebas
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar un componente de `React` que tenga un `state`.

Te adjunto el ejemplo de como podría resolverse tu problema.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opciones: []
    };

    this.handleNumberChange = this.handleNumberChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNumberChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let opciones = [];
    opciones.push(value - 1);
    let valueTimesTwo = value * 2;
    opciones.push(valueTimesTwo);
    opciones.push(valueTimesTwo * 2);

    this.setState({
      opciones: opciones
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="ingrese un numero"
          onChange={this.handleNumberChange}
        />
        <br />

        <select name="tipo_cancha" className="form-control">
          <option value="no" selected>
            seleccionar
          </option>
          {this.state.opciones.map((opcion) => (
            <option value={opcion}>{opcion}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Tienes que tener un estado en el que guardes las opciones del `select`. Cuando haya un cambio en tu `input`, recibes el evento, y actualizas el estado con los nuevos valores de las opciones.

Puedes ver como funciona el ejemplo en el siguiente link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/select-change-from-input-xgrqy?file=/src/App.js